# What does double ampersand do in bpf filter?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm reading bpf(berkeley packet filter) core part in linux kernel, and I'm a little bit confused in the following.
This is the part of the code:

```c
static unsigned int ___bpf_prog_run(u64 *regs, const struct bpf_insn *insn,
                    u64 *stack)
{
    u64 tmp;
    static const void *jumptable[256] = {
        [0 ... 255] = &&default_label,
        /* Now overwrite non-defaults ... */
        /* 32 bit ALU operations */
        [BPF_ALU | BPF_ADD | BPF_X] = &&ALU_ADD_X,
        [BPF_ALU | BPF_ADD | BPF_K] = &&ALU_ADD_K,
        [BPF_ALU | BPF_SUB | BPF_X] = &&ALU_SUB_X,
        [BPF_ALU | BPF_SUB | BPF_K] = &&ALU_SUB_K,
```

So, what I am wondering is a role of the double ampersand. I already know about rvalue reference in C++, but it is C, not C++, isn't it?

I am so appreciate the help!

Comment: This is c and not c++

Comment: Pretty sure the double ampersand is a GCC extension that allows you to take the address of a label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this were C++, `&&ALU_ADD_X` and so on are expressions, not types, so the `&&` couldn't indicate an rvalue reference.

If you scroll down a bit, you will find that all the `ALU_*` things, and `default_label`, are labels.
You will also find a `goto *jumptable[op];`, where `op` is a number.

GCC has an extension where you can take the "address" of a label as a value and use it as the target for `goto`.
`&&` is the operator that produces such a value.

A shorter example:

```
void example() 
{
    void* where = test_stuff() ? &&here : &&there;
    goto *where;
    here:
        do_something();
        return;   
    there:
        do_something_else();
}
```

There's more information in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) (which is pretty much impossible to find unless you know what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

see this document.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

It likes gcc non-standard syntax.